# Update new column with part of JSON column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-update

I have a json column titled 'classifiers' with data like this:

```
[ { "category": "Building & Trades", "type": "Services"
  , "subcategory": "Construction" } ]
```

I would like to pull each element and insert into columns on the same row titled, for example, 'category', 'type' and 'subcategory'.

This query pulls out what I want, in this case 'category':

```
SELECT parts->'category' AS category
FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(classifiers) AS parts FROM <tablename>) AS more_parts
```

I can't figure out the 'WHERE' part in an UPDATE/SET/WHERE type of query, for example:

```
UPDATE <table>
SET category = (SELECT parts->'category' AS category
                FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(classifiers) AS parts
                      FROM <tablename>
                     ) AS more_parts
               ) WHERE ???
```

Without `WHERE` multiple rows are returned.

Comment: Your Postgres version? And `json_array_elements()` returns a set of values. You have to define *somehow* which one to pick. Or use a different function / operator if there can only be one.

Comment: Postgres 9.3. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to pull each element and insert into columns on the same
>   row titled, for example, 'category', 'type' and 'subcategory'.

Sounds like you really want this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    category = classifiers->0->'category'
      ,type = classifiers->0->'type'
      ,subcategory = classifiers->0->'subcategory'
```

Updates all rows. Requires Postgres 9.3+.

- The first operator `->0` reverences the only object in the array (json array index starting from 0 unlike Postgres arrays, which start from 1 per default).
- The second operator `->'category'` gets the field from the object.

[Refer to the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html)